# Using shapeless HLists with invariant containers

Tags: scala, shapeless

Suppose the elements of an `HList` are subclasses of a generic trait.   Each element is contained in `case class Box[E](elem E)`. That `Box` is *invariant* in `E`  causes problems with mapping a `poly1` over `HList`, selecting an element by its parent trait, etc. Here's an example:

```
import shapeless._

trait Drink[+A]{ def v: A}

case class Water(v: Int) extends Drink[Int]
case class Juice(v: BigDecimal) extends Drink[BigDecimal]
case class Squash(v: BigDecimal) extends Drink[BigDecimal]


case class Box[E](elem: E) // NB! invariance in E

object pour extends Poly1{

  implicit def caseInt[A <: Box[Drink[Int]]] =  at[A](o => Box(o.elem.v * 2))
  implicit def caseDec[A <: Box[Drink[BigDecimal]]] = at[A](o => Box(o.elem.v + 5.0))
}


object Proc {

  type I = Box[Water] :: Box[Squash] :: Box[Juice] ::  HNil
  type O = Box[Int] :: Box[BigDecimal] :: Box[BigDecimal] :: HNil

  val drinks: I = Box(Water(10)) :: Box(Squash(15.0)) :: Box(Juice(2.0)) :: HNil

  def make()(implicit m: ops.hlist.Mapper.Aux[pour.type, I, O]): O = drinks.map(pour)
}


object Main extends App{
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =  Proc.make()
}
```

*The function `pour` applies the answer by @Jasper_M to [Mapping over HList with subclasses of a generic trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48120465/mapping-over-hlist-with-subclasses-of-a-generic-trait).

This code leads to 
`Error:(38, 22) could not find implicit value for parameter m: shapeless.ops.hlist.Mapper.Aux[pour.type,Proc.I,Proc.O] 
 Proc.make()`. 
Also, filtering `Proc.drinks.covariantFilter[Box[Drink[Int]]]` produces `HNil`. (This filter implements the answer by @Travis Brown to  [Do a covariant filter on an HList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713668/do-a-covariant-filter-on-an-hlist).)

Defining `Box[+E]`, which solves the problems, is not possible in my project. A naive solution -- to have a case in the `pour` for each subclass of `Drink` -- does not scale. (This could be made to work by passing monomorphic functions to `pour`, which I don't know how.)

Could there be a more sensible approach to mapping or filtering over HLists in this set-up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case where all your outer type constructors are `Box`, you can apply almost the same technique as in my previous answer:

```
object pour extends Poly1{
  implicit def caseInt[A <: Drink[Int]] =  at[Box[A]](o => Box(o.elem.v * 2))
  implicit def caseDec[A <: Drink[BigDecimal]] = at[Box[A]](o => Box(o.elem.v + 5.0))
}
```

Now if your type of `Box` is also polymorphic, you can still go a step further:

```
import shapeless._

trait Drink[+A]{ def v: A}

case class Water(v: Int) extends Drink[Int]
case class Juice(v: BigDecimal) extends Drink[BigDecimal]
case class Squash(v: BigDecimal) extends Drink[BigDecimal]

trait Box[E] { def elem: E}
case class ABox[E](elem: E) extends Box[E]
case class BBox[E](elem: E) extends Box[E]

object pour extends Poly1{
  implicit def caseInt[A <: Drink[Int], M[x] <: Box[x]] = at[M[A]](o => o.elem.v * 2)
  implicit def caseDec[A <: Drink[BigDecimal], M[x] <: Box[x]] = at[M[A]](o => o.elem.v + 5.0)
}


val drinks = ABox(Water(10)) :: BBox(Squash(15.0)) :: ABox(Juice(2.0)) :: HNil

drinks.map(pour)
```

You may have noticed I didn't re-wrap the values in its box in this last example. You could still do that, for instance if you implement something like a `trait Boxer[M[_]] { def box[A](a: A): M[A] }` typeclass, or with F-bounded polymorphism in `Box`, but that would probably lead us too far.